# Better landing page for users without site access

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, private-beta, unregistered-users

Pre-beta the site only is accessible to those of us who committed on Area51. The site landing (the index) shows a login page to users who do not yet have access, and a message suggesting that they read the FAQ, and yet they cannot login to the site and if they click the FAQ link they are redirected to the same login...

**Is it possible to improve the experience for non-users, pre-beta?**

Note: To see what I'm referring to, try logging out of the site and attempting to access a question. I'm certain we've got people sending emails with links to questions/answers already... Who knows? They may even be posting links on their blogs.

Answer (score 2):

This condition will only exist for 7 single days, ever, for the entire history of time.

Are you sure it's worth fixing?

edit: we made it so the users/login page does not trigger the faq topbar. Verified in Google Incognito mode.

Comment: ...for every site created... ever...

Comment: Good point, fretje.  @Jeff, it would be interesting to see statistics of how many registered stackoverflow and area51 users logged into that page and were rejected with no explanation.  How many of those users do you think will came back for the beta?